# Breeze with third party API

Tags: breeze

Is it possible for Breeze to access a third party API that does not have a "BreezeController" nor supports OData?

Answer (score 0):

"BreezeController" is simply a .NET attribute that helps .NET WebApi provide support for query filtering and ordering via OData "syntax" and well as json serialization support for entity graphs and type identity.  Type identity is important so that breeze can track the entities within its entityManager and merge the results of queries and update relation properties. OData itself is never required.

If you don't want the ability for the client to add filtering and ordering instructions to the server, you can write your own attribute that simply provides the json serialization support.  The json serialization consists simply of configuring the json.net formatter that web api is already using.

The source for the BreezeControllerAttribute may be found in the Breeze.WebApi project and is really pretty short.  Just create your own 'FooControllerAttribute' by copying the 'BreezeControllerAttribute' and remove the IFilterProvider code.

On the other hand, the query and filtering support won't hurt anything and this logic isn't even applied unless you use the EntityQuery 'where' 'orderBy' 'select' or 'expand' methods, so unless you want to explicitly remove this ability there is no need to not use the 'breezeControllerAttribute'

Comment: But it seems that Breeze client do not recognizes the json response when it comes without metadata. Look the attribute $type at the response of [todo sample](http://todo.breezejs.com/api/todos/Todos?$filter=IsArchived%20eq%20false&$orderby=CreatedAt). The API that my client is talking to doesn´t have this attribute $type, I think it causes my Breeze client to return Object instead of instantiate a registered EntityType.

Comment: You are correct, right now we need the $type attribute, provided by configuring the json.net serializer, in order to recognize the type and merge the data into the entityManager, otherwise query results get returned as plain objects. We are actively working on a way for a dev to tell the client about the types returned from a query or for the breeze client to be provided with inference rules so that it can determine the type of a response without it being explicitly provided by the server.

Comment: It would be nice! Is it planned? 
Or it´d be better to suggest at http://breezejs.uservoice.com?

Comment: It is planned.  I will post back here when it gets in.

Comment: This capability is now available as of v 1.2.1. (See JsonResultsAdapter).  I will be documenting it more fully over the next few days.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that.